# Performace Slow down on click of button + codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I'm calling REST Calls on click of the methods. I see significant slow down of the App where ever button clicks are involved.
1. I see following error in console.Please advise if any one notice similar issue.

2. Most the times button needs to be clicked twice to proceed

Error Log 1:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paint(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:648)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Error Log 2:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode cannot be cast to com.codename1.ui.Component
Rendering frame took too long 972 milliseconds
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.PerformanceMonitor.componentHierarchyValueChanged(PerformanceMonitor.java:413)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.PerformanceMonitor.access$1000(PerformanceMonitor.java:77)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.PerformanceMonitor$FormListener.valueChanged(PerformanceMonitor.java:345)
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2927)
    at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3391)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:635)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1093)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:294)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:188)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(JTree.java:1634)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(BasicTreeUI.java:2393)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(BasicTreeUI.java:3609)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTreeUI.java:3548)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6530)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4523)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression in the performance monitor due to a change in the JDK. Just close it and it shouldn't impact performance anymore. It only applies to the simulator obviously.

It's fixed [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/cf6b14d97252f14f7e661ffb59be320e37e3076d) and will be available in the next update of the client on Friday September 7th 2018.

Comment: Thank You Shai. I do see  a problem with button where I end up clicking twice to take effect. First click make the button pressed and second click will make it work. Please advise if  there is any regression on button action as well. Thanks

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Check the console and see if the debug breakpoint is reached